# Since when Gowther become one of Ten Commandments?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I know that Gowther is one of Seven Deadly Sins, but in later manga, it is revealed that he also one of Ten Commandments.

So, since when he is become one of them? Did he join Ten Commandments after or before he join in Seven Deadly Sins?

Comment: I don't know which part that could be spoiler for anime, because the next season of this anime still upcoming event. So, feel free to add spoiler tags.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other material out there, but from what I know of the manga, this part is still unanswered and will probably be answered in the upcoming chapters once we know more of the ten commands, their relation to meliodas and the history of the war in general.

Comment: Before the seven sins. Dreyfus has been looking for him. It was stated when he was fighting the two old dudes.

Comment: @ton.yeung two old dudes...?

Comment: The whole point of the reveal was that Gowther was a Ten commandment, but specifics about which commandment he was, as well as when he was one and how he lost that power have not been revealed yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has already been 3 thousand years with respect to the current events when the 10 Commandments fought for their race and were defeated and sealed away. Meliodas himself being a demon was definitely involved and witnessed it all. He has been alive all these thousands of years.

The Seven Deadly Sins were formed much more recently. The Seven Deadly Sins were an independent group of knights serving the Kingdom of Liones. So it is obvious that they have been around for a while but only during the time of Liones.

Gowther was recently revealed to be a doll created by a great magician. Meliodas is a demon. King is a fairy. Diane is a Giant and Ban is an immortal. Those explain why they have such long life spans. But the true nature of Escanor and Merlin has not been revealed yet.

Still, the Kingdom of Liones was probably founded much later after the 10 Commandments were defeated. The back stories of some of the characters have been revealed before they joined The Seven Deadly Sins. Ban and Diane for instance. They have been shown to be in their younger years living in pretty much the same timeline as the current one with no demons. So it is safe to assume that The Seven Deadly Sins were created fairly recently as compared the thousands of years.

Gowther is revealed to be "Gowther the Selfless" of the 10 Commandments. He lost his memories because of his selflessness. By the time he joined the Sins, he had no memories of his past. That means he must have been a part of the 10 Commandments before he had joined the Sins.

It is unclear though whether he was part of the 10 Commandments back when they were defeated 3 thousand years ago or became a part of them afterwards like Fraudrin. If Gowther was a part of the 10 commandments back then, then Meliodas probably knows about him and hasn't revealed the truth to anyone thus far.

**UPDATE:**
Some of Gowther's past was revealed to King and Diane by Gloxinia, the former fairy king and Dolor, the former giant king. Gowther himself was a part of the 10 commandments long before the war between the clans even started. However, he had been imprisoned by the Demon King. The Gowther we know is just a doll created by the real Gowther, released into the real world to be his eyes and ears.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the last episode, he says, "I am Gowther of the seven deadly sins, sparkle." Then right after that he says, "I am Gowther of selflessness of the ten commandments, sparkle." So yes, he is, I believe his commandment is if you are selfless, you lose your memory.

That was the last words in season 3, so it left us on a major cliffhanger.

Really, Gowther is the name of a demon mage that was recognized about 500 years before the Holy War. He unwillingly became a part of the ten commandments.

But currently, Gowther has been out of commission for a while now, so they simply put Fraudrin in as a substitute for the real Gowther. Fraudrin has no real commandment, and was seen in the anime with the doll Gowther, as the doll Gowther tells Fraudrin that Melodis has betrayed the demon race.(And Fraudrin was freaking out)

The Doll Gowther was created to be the eyes and ears for the mage Gowther as he regained his power, but I have a feeling the doll Gowther has a mind of it's own.

There is no evidence on this next theory, but i believe that the whole reason Gowther joined The Seven deadly Sins was to weaken their forces so the demon Gowther could reach Meliodis quicker.

So the answer to your question is... He became one of the Ten Commandments well before the Holy War(Demon Gowther). So the doll Gowther is only a vessel for him to see what's happening, so the Doll Gowther joined the seven deadly sins, as the demon did not, So the Gowther that is a doll is more of a tool to the Ten Commandments.(I really hope this helped you out. Bye now!)